# How to add Array in parse.com Dashboard?

Tags: arrays, dashboard, parse-platform

can anyone tell me how to format the input when trying to add a new array in a column field?

it just doesnt take my input and i havent found anything neither in the documentation nor the web nor stackoverflow.

i'd be glad if anyone could help me.

greets

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The format for an array would be:

```
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Note that you do need double quotes. Single quotes get silently dropped.

Comment: @Hector Ramos - I have column 'categories' and i want to set option in column to select category from list, like, boolean data type shows only 2 option either true or false. like wise i want to set pre- defined option in categories filed. is it possible, if yes please guide.